Can't get DirectX 12 Vertex Buffer Output Stream working (results are full of zeros)
I've been having trouble trying to implement DirectX 12 vertex buffer output stream to get the world transformed vertex positions. I almost have it working - it does everything no errors but it returns 0 for the counter and zeros for the output stream data. I started with simple code that I can share to hopefully solve it. I have googled, chat gpted, and used the dxcpl.exe to force debug messages on.
I started with BzTut 04:
https://www.braynzarsoft.net/viewtutorial/q16390-04-direct3d-12-drawing
And ended up with:
https://github.com/ryan-de-boer/DirectX12SampleCode
Here is some of the code, where counterValue is zero and streamOutputData is full of zeros.
The vertex shader
struct VertexOutput // also in pixel shader as input
{
  float3 position : POSITION; // Stream out 3*4bytes
  float3 worldPos: WORLDPOS; // Stream out world pos position 3*4bytes
  float4 sv_position : SV_POSITION; // Stream out position 4*4bytes, total 40bytes
};

struct VertexInput
{
  float3 position : POSITION; // Stream out 3*4bytes
  float3 worldPos: WORLDPOS; // Stream out world pos position 3*4bytes
  float4 sv_position : SV_POSITION; // Stream out position 4*4bytes, total 40bytes
};

VertexOutput main(VertexInput input)
{
  VertexOutput vo;
  vo.worldPos = float3(1.1f, 1.2f, 1.3f); // I know this should be localPosition * world transform, but I want something simple working first.
  vo.position = input.position;
  vo.sv_position = float4(input.position, 1.0f);
  return vo;
}

main:
    D3D12_STREAM_OUTPUT_BUFFER_VIEW streamOutputBufferView = {};
    streamOutputBufferView.BufferFilledSizeLocation = streamOutputBuffer->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
    streamOutputBufferView.BufferLocation = streamOutputBufferView.BufferFilledSizeLocation + sizeof(UINT64);
    streamOutputBufferView.SizeInBytes = bufferSize;/* Size of the buffer */;


    // Bind the output buffer to the stream-output stage

    commandList->SOSetTargets(0/* Start slot */, 1/* Number of views */, &streamOutputBufferView);


    commandList->DrawInstanced(3, 1, 0, 0); // finally draw 3 vertices (draw the triangle)


    // Transition the state of the source buffer to D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_SOURCE
    CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER barrier = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(
        streamOutputBuffer,                   // Resource
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_STREAM_OUT,            // From state
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_SOURCE           // To state
    );

    // Insert the barrier into the command list
    commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &barrier);
    // Define the heap properties
    D3D12_HEAP_PROPERTIES heapProperties = {};
    heapProperties.Type = D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD; // Use UPLOAD type for CPU-accessible heap
    heapProperties.CPUPageProperty = D3D12_CPU_PAGE_PROPERTY_UNKNOWN; // Specify CPU visibility
    heapProperties.MemoryPoolPreference = D3D12_MEMORY_POOL_UNKNOWN; // Use default memory pool

    // Define the buffer description
    CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC bufferDesc = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(totalBufferSize);

    // Create the destination buffer in the CPU-accessible heap
    ID3D12Resource* destinationBuffer;
    device->CreateCommittedResource(
        &heapProperties,                        // Heap properties
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,                   // Flags
        &bufferDesc,                            // Resource description
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ,      // Initial resource state
        nullptr,                                // Clear value (unused for buffers)
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&destinationBuffer)        // Destination pointer
    );


    // Calculate the size of the counter (assuming UINT64)
    const UINT counterSize = sizeof(UINT64);

    // Calculate the total size of the data to copy
    const UINT totalDataSize = totalBufferSize;

    // Perform the copy
    commandList->CopyBufferRegion(
        destinationBuffer,     // Destination buffer
        0,                           // Destination offset
        streamOutputBuffer,    // Source buffer
        0,                           // Source offset
        totalDataSize                // Size to copy
    );


    // Map the destination buffer to CPU-accessible memory
    UINT8* mappedData = nullptr;
    CD3DX12_RANGE readRange(0, 0); // We'll read the entire buffer
  hr = destinationBuffer->Map(0, &readRange, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&mappedData));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"MAP FAILED");
    }

    // Copy the data from the mapped memory
    // Assuming the first sizeof(UINT64) bytes contain the counter and the rest contain the stream output data
    UINT64 counterValue = *reinterpret_cast<UINT64*>(mappedData);
    BYTE* streamOutputData = mappedData + sizeof(UINT64);
    // Now you can use counterValue and streamOutputData as needed

    // Unmap the buffer
    destinationBuffer->Unmap(0, nullptr);


    commandList->SOSetTargets(0/* Start slot */, 0/* Number of views */, nullptr);

See my github link for the rest of the code and you can compile with VS2022. I also added a screenshot of PIX running on the sample code and you can see it knows how to get the world transformed position in the VS output buffer.

Good news, I've managed to successfully extract a simple float from a vertex output stream. Its from an exmple that has a geometry shader, hopefully I can get it to work without one.
Here is the example code that I started from.
https://paminerva.github.io/docs/LearnDirectX/02.D-Simple-Rain-Effect.html
https://github.com/PAMinerva/LearnDirectX-samples

I fixed the destination buffer filled with zeros problem. The key solution was executing the command list before reading the buffer from CopyResource.
Here are the recent changes I made to the github sample:

For destinationBuffer instead of D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ I used D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST.
Instead of CopyBufferRegion I used CopyReource.
Execute command list to wait for CopyResource to complete.
Can now save the binary data out!

See a screenshot of HxD viewing the binary data on my github page.
